# Two bootstrap rows not aligning correctly when responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

So I'm developing this website, and the client wants the honeycomb pattern as shown: **http://27.121.66.1/~scsc1126/test.html**

It looks the way I want in regular mode, but in responsive mode instead of the hexagons sitting neatly on top of each other, the second set is offset to the right.  I have no idea why.  I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't figure it out.

Here's the code:

```css
.icon-row-1 {
 position: relative;
 clear: both;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 width: 90%;
}
.icon-row-2 {
 float: none;
 position: relative;
 clear: both;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1> COMPETITIONS </h1>
  <p>&nbsp; </p>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="icon-row-1">
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/competition/crystal-growing/">
        <h2> Titration </h2>
        <img alt="titration" src="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/titration.png"/></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/competition/crystal-growing/">
        <h2> Crystal Growing </h2>
        <img alt="crystal growing" src="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/crystal-growing.png"/></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/competition/ancq/">
        <h2> ANCQ </h2>
        <img alt="ancq" src="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ancq.png"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="icon-row-2">
      <div class="col-md-6"> <a href="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/store/"><img alt="store" class="alignnone wp-image-42 size-full" height="347" src="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/store.png" width="301" />
        <h2> Visit the Store </h2>
        </a></div>
      <div class="col-md-6"> <a href="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/other-initiatives/"><img alt="other-initiatives" class="alignnone wp-image-1123 size-full" height="347" src="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/other-initiatives.png" width="301" />
        <h2> Other Initiatives </h2>
        </a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong???  It's driving me nuts.

Comment: add your html code in the question

Answer (score 0):

```css
   

 img{max-width: 100%; height: auto;}
    .icon-row-1 {
     position: relative;
     clear: both;
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     width: 90%;
    }
    .icon-row-2 {
     float: none;
     position: relative;
     clear: both;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     width: 60%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <h1> COMPETITIONS </h1>
      <p>&nbsp; </p>
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="icon-row-1">
          <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/competition/crystal-growing/">
            <h2> Titration </h2>
            <img alt="titration" src="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/titration.png"/></a></div>
          <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/competition/crystal-growing/">
            <h2> Crystal Growing </h2>
            <img alt="crystal growing" src="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/crystal-growing.png"/></a></div>
          <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/competition/ancq/">
            <h2> ANCQ </h2>
            <img alt="ancq" src="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ancq.png"></a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="icon-row-2">
          <div class="col-md-6"> <a href="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/store/"><img alt="store" class="alignnone wp-image-42 size-full" height="347" src="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/store.png" width="301" />
            <h2> Visit the Store </h2>
            </a></div>
          <div class="col-md-6"> <a href="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/other-initiatives/"><img alt="other-initiatives" class="alignnone wp-image-1123 size-full" height="347" src="http://schools.raci.org.au/wp/beta/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/other-initiatives.png" width="301" />
            <h2> Other Initiatives </h2>
            </a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This CSS

```
img {
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  the images are now stacking correctly, but we've created a new problem.  The second set of images is smaller than the first for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qu6z2cLd/)
Add this css:

```
img {
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
```

}